# Duplicate layers when reusing pytorch model

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to reuse some of the resnet layers for a custom architecture and ran into a issue I can't figure out. Here is a simplified example; when I run:

```
import torch
from torchvision import models
from torchsummary import summary

def convrelu(in_channels, out_channels, kernel, padding):
    return nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel, padding=padding),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    )


class ResNetUNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.base_model = models.resnet18(pretrained=False)
        self.base_layers = list(self.base_model.children())


        self.layer0 = nn.Sequential(*self.base_layers[:3])


    def forward(self, x):
        print(x.shape)

        output = self.layer0(x)

        return output

base_model = ResNetUNet().cuda()
summary(base_model,(3,224,224))
```

Is giving me:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1         [-1, 64, 112, 112]           9,408
            Conv2d-2         [-1, 64, 112, 112]           9,408
       BatchNorm2d-3         [-1, 64, 112, 112]             128
       BatchNorm2d-4         [-1, 64, 112, 112]             128
              ReLU-5         [-1, 64, 112, 112]               0
              ReLU-6         [-1, 64, 112, 112]               0
================================================================
Total params: 19,072
Trainable params: 19,072
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.57
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 36.75
Params size (MB): 0.07
Estimated Total Size (MB): 37.40
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is duplicating each layer (there are 2 convs, 2 batchnorms, 2 relu's) as opposed to giving one layer each. If I print out `self.base_layers[:3]` I get:

`[Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False), BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True), ReLU(inplace=True)]`

which shows just three layers without duplicates. Why is it duplicating my layers?

I am using pytorch version 1.4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your layers aren't actually being invoked twice. This is an artifact of how `summary` is implemented.

The simple reason is because `summary` recursively iterates over all the children of your module and registers forward hooks for each of them. Since you have repeated children (in `base_model` and `layer0`) then those repeated modules get multiple hooks registered. When summary calls forward this causes both of the hooks for each module to be invoked which causes repeats of the layers to be reported.

---

For your toy example a solution would be to simply not assign `base_model` as an attribute since it's not being used during forward anyway. This avoids having `base_model` ever being added as a child.

```
class ResNetUNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        base_model = models.resnet18(pretrained=False)
        base_layers = list(base_model.children())
        self.layer0 = nn.Sequential(*base_layers[:3])
```

---

Another solution is to create a modified version of `summary` which doesn't register hooks for the same module multiple times. Below is an augmented `summary` where I use a set named `already_registered` to keep track of modules which already have hooks registered to avoid registering multiple hooks.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np

def summary(model, input_size, batch_size=-1, device="cuda"):

    # keep track of registered modules so that we don't add multiple hooks
    already_registered = set()

    def register_hook(module):

        def hook(module, input, output):
            class_name = str(module.__class__).split(".")[-1].split("'")[0]
            module_idx = len(summary)

            m_key = "%s-%i" % (class_name, module_idx + 1)
            summary[m_key] = OrderedDict()
            summary[m_key]["input_shape"] = list(input[0].size())
            summary[m_key]["input_shape"][0] = batch_size
            if isinstance(output, (list, tuple)):
                summary[m_key]["output_shape"] = [
                    [-1] + list(o.size())[1:] for o in output
                ]
            else:
                summary[m_key]["output_shape"] = list(output.size())
                summary[m_key]["output_shape"][0] = batch_size

            params = 0
            if hasattr(module, "weight") and hasattr(module.weight, "size"):
                params += torch.prod(torch.LongTensor(list(module.weight.size())))
                summary[m_key]["trainable"] = module.weight.requires_grad
            if hasattr(module, "bias") and hasattr(module.bias, "size"):
                params += torch.prod(torch.LongTensor(list(module.bias.size())))
            summary[m_key]["nb_params"] = params

        if (
            not isinstance(module, nn.Sequential)
            and not isinstance(module, nn.ModuleList)
            and not (module == model)
            and module not in already_registered:
        ):
            already_registered.add(module)
            hooks.append(module.register_forward_hook(hook))

    device = device.lower()
    assert device in [
        "cuda",
        "cpu",
    ], "Input device is not valid, please specify 'cuda' or 'cpu'"

    if device == "cuda" and torch.cuda.is_available():
        dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor
    else:
        dtype = torch.FloatTensor

    # multiple inputs to the network
    if isinstance(input_size, tuple):
        input_size = [input_size]

    # batch_size of 2 for batchnorm
    x = [torch.rand(2, *in_size).type(dtype) for in_size in input_size]
    # print(type(x[0]))

    # create properties
    summary = OrderedDict()
    hooks = []

    # register hook
    model.apply(register_hook)

    # make a forward pass
    # print(x.shape)
    model(*x)

    # remove these hooks
    for h in hooks:
        h.remove()

    print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    line_new = "{:>20}  {:>25} {:>15}".format("Layer (type)", "Output Shape", "Param #")
    print(line_new)
    print("================================================================")
    total_params = 0
    total_output = 0
    trainable_params = 0
    for layer in summary:
        # input_shape, output_shape, trainable, nb_params
        line_new = "{:>20}  {:>25} {:>15}".format(
            layer,
            str(summary[layer]["output_shape"]),
            "{0:,}".format(summary[layer]["nb_params"]),
        )
        total_params += summary[layer]["nb_params"]
        total_output += np.prod(summary[layer]["output_shape"])
        if "trainable" in summary[layer]:
            if summary[layer]["trainable"] == True:
                trainable_params += summary[layer]["nb_params"]
        print(line_new)

    # assume 4 bytes/number (float on cuda).
    total_input_size = abs(np.prod(input_size) * batch_size * 4. / (1024 ** 2.))
    total_output_size = abs(2. * total_output * 4. / (1024 ** 2.))  # x2 for gradients
    total_params_size = abs(total_params.numpy() * 4. / (1024 ** 2.))
    total_size = total_params_size + total_output_size + total_input_size

    print("================================================================")
    print("Total params: {0:,}".format(total_params))
    print("Trainable params: {0:,}".format(trainable_params))
    print("Non-trainable params: {0:,}".format(total_params - trainable_params))
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Input size (MB): %0.2f" % total_input_size)
    print("Forward/backward pass size (MB): %0.2f" % total_output_size)
    print("Params size (MB): %0.2f" % total_params_size)
    print("Estimated Total Size (MB): %0.2f" % total_size)
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    # return summary
```